# avoiding retain cycles for UITableView done programmatically from a ViewController that is a child of another ViewController

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a ViewController named MainViewController that acts as the central page for the app. This MainViewController has 6 properties in it  that are instances of other viewControllers

```
lazy var shelvesView: ShelvesViewController = {
    return ShelvesViewController()
}()
lazy var goalsView: GoalsViewController = {
    return GoalsViewController()
}()
lazy var shoppingView: ShoppingListViewController = {
    return ShoppingListViewController()
}()
lazy var tipsView: TipsViewController = {
    return TipsViewController()
}()
lazy var myDenView: MyDenViewController = {
    return MyDenViewController()
}()
lazy var settingsview: SettingsViewController = {
    return SettingsViewController()
}()
```

when the mainViewController loads it starts out with the shelvesViewController laid over it just underneath the mainViewControllers custom NavBar like so

```
func setupShelvesView() {
    shelvesView.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
    addChildViewController(shelvesView)
    self.view.addSubview(shelvesView.view)
    shelvesView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height * 0.08, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - (view.frame.height * 0.08))
    shelvesView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    globalCurrentView = 1
}
```

I also have a menu that slides over this mainViewController with a list of different pages the user can navigate to. when the user switches to a new page, say the goalsViewController, the shelvesViewController will be animated off screen, removed from the parentViewController(MainViewController) and the goalsViewController will be initialized, moved to the MainViewController and animated onscreen in the same frame as the shelvesView. Anytime i switch a VC from the menu i use this method.

```
func changeVCfrom(OldVC oldVC: UIViewController, newVC: UIViewController) {

    let newStartFrame = CGRect(x: 0 + self.view.frame.width, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - (view.frame.height * 0.08))

    let newEndframe = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height * 0.08, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - (view.frame.height * 0.08))

    let oldfinishFrame = CGRect(x: 0 - self.view.frame.width, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

    oldVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    self.addChildViewController(newVC)
    newVC.view.frame = newStartFrame


    transition(from: oldVC, to: newVC, duration: 0.2, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
        oldVC.view.frame = oldfinishFrame
        newVC.view.frame = newEndframe
    }, completion: { (success) in
        oldVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        oldVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        oldVC.removeFromParentViewController()
        newVC.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
        self.view.addSubview(newVC.view)
    })
}
```

the problem here is that i have done all my views programmatically and any of the above viewControllers(lazy properties) that have a tableView propery on them have a memory leak. any time the VC goes off the MainViewController the memory used for the tableView is not being dealocated and anytime it comes back on the MainViewController is is being allocated again for more memory.

as of right now this is how ive been setting up my tableViews

```
let tableView = UITableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupObjects()
    tableView.register(ShelfTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "shelfCell")
}
func setupTableView() {
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    setupTableViewConstraints()
}
func setupTableViewConstraints() {
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

I understand that I need to have my tableviews either weak, unowned or somehow get the tableview to completely deallocate when off screen. but whatever i try I get errors all over the place that i cant resolve or my ViewController is not able to load the tableview. I apologize for the lengthy question, but any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while scrolling up and down on the tableView my memory would go up sharply. Turns out i had set up the dequeReusableCell wrong.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = ShelfTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "shelfCell")
    tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shelfCell", for: indexPath)
    if let shelf = UserController.shared.user?.shelves?[indexPath.row] as? Shelf {
        cell.shelf = shelf
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

essentially what was happening was every time the viewWillAppear was hit i reloaded the tableViewData which ran this code

```
    let cell = ShelfTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "shelfCell")
    tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shelfCell", for: indexPath)
```

which was causing the memory leak

replacing the above code with the following resolved the issue

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shelfCell", for: indexPath) as! ShelfTableViewCell
    if let shelf = UserController.shared.user?.shelves?[indexPath.row] as? Shelf {
        cell.shelf = shelf
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The table views are not getting deallocated when your child view controllers go off screen.

Your MainViewController owns those other view controllers. Yes, they're lazy, but once they're called for the first time they are initialized along with the tableviews they own.

The child view controllers are not deallocated by simply moving them offscreen. All you're doing is changing the frame and removing them as a child view controller of MainViewController. Since the they're still in memory, the table view is also still in memory.

If you really want to deallocate the table view every time the controller moves off screen, you can just set

```
self.tableView = nil
```

There shouldn't be a retain cycle here because the tableView's datasource and delegate properties are `weak`, meaning that they don't increase the reference count of the view controller.

Comment: I found out that the memory leak wasn't from the tableview but from the dequeReusableCell. I appreciate the help!